# Why is the elements text not changing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to change the text of this element. However it is not working. Here is the header im trying to change - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtcT9.png)

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("headertext");
elem.innerHTML = "hello world";
```

```html
<ul class="headertable">
  <li>
    <p class="headertext">Home</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="headertext">About US</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="headertext">Contact US</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? your given code is not clear

Comment: @Usman I have tried moving the script tags and changing the the getElementsByClassName to .getElementsByTagName.

Comment: @Usman I'm trying to use the JS code to change the text inside the HTML class "headertext".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s).

Here the `elem` will be an `HTMLCollection`. So `elem.innerHTML` is not valid.

So you should use the index to update the required node

like `elem[0].innerHTML` or `elem[1].innerHTML` or `elem[2].innerHTML`

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("headertext");
elem[0].innerHTML = "hello world";
elem[1].innerHTML = "hello world 1";
elem[2].innerHTML = "hello world 2";
```

```html
<ul class="headertable">
    <li><p class="headertext">Home</p></li>
    <li><p class="headertext">About US</p></li>
    <li><p class="headertext">Contact US</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is still not changing my elements on my browser?

Comment: @Zeronir That code should work in all popular modern browsers. Do you run your code with a [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event handeler?

Comment: Please ensure that your script tag is below your element. So that the script can access your dom elements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Comment: @Zeronir the example given here works fine for me. If that is the case for you as well, but it does not work when you try it within your site - well then we need a _proper_ problem description from your first of all. You need to provide a proper [mre] of your issue in such cases.

Comment: SO fiddle places the script snippet below its body tag so that the script can asscess the elements inside template. Your template should be something like this <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Your Template</div>
  <script>
    //Your script
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Nitheesh Yes it works now. My script tag was within the head tag. Thanks a lot.